# HTML if and only if logic

Tags: html

In my html view I currently have the following logic (simplified)

```
 if (a != 0 && b!=0 && c!=0 && d!=0)
    draw table rows
```

However, it does not do exactly what I need. The logic I need is: "don't draw rows only if all 4 variables = 0, in all other cases draw it"

Is there a way to implement 'only if' logic on the html part, or I should apply that logic on SQL side?

Comment: There is no logic in html...:) Btw, which server side language you use?

Comment: HTML is just a markup language, it cant do logic like that. You need to use some js framework like vuejs or angular to work directly on the html

Comment: that's why a programmer needs to know Boolean algebra

Comment: @derloopkat Sigh, agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the 4 variables is not equal to 0

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0 || d != 0)
```

or

```
if (!(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not html, sql or any technology

it is a math logic problem

The logic I need is: "don't draw rows only if all 4 variables = 0, in all other cases draw it"

```
if (a == 0 && b==0 && c==0 && d==0)
  // nothing
else 
  draw table rows
```

which is the same as

```
if (!(a == 0 && b==0 && c==0 && d==0))
  draw table rows
```

or

```
if (a != 0 || b!=0 || c!=0 || d!=0))
  draw table rows
```

because "negation of (A and B)"  is "not A or not B"

Comment: Both answers work, but abney was first to respond. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, because I was writing a longer answer... I submitted my answer few seconds after the first one. I believed the community cares more about the explanation rather than a simple solution.

Comment: I was testing the solution from the other answer, and I received your answer by the time I already confirmed it was working. Sorry about that. That's why I gave you upvote, since I knew your answer would work as well. I just happened to see your solution too late.